# Is there a way to use loops and buttons to display product and quotients of array numbers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, button

Need help with assignment. I need to create a button that uses a for loop to multiply each number in the array by the number after it into a second array and display the result. Lastly create another button that uses a while loop that divides each number in the array by the number after it into a third array and once more display the result. I have created a way to input numbers into an array "numbers" and sisplay the array but do not know how to use for loops to display the quotient nor the product please help :(

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<input type="number" id="num" min="0" max="100">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<button onclick="SortFunction()">Sort it</button>
<button onclick="AddFunction()">Add it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var myarray =[] ;
var text ;

function myFunction()
{
var fLen ;
var x = document.getElementById("num").value;
var i ;
myarray.push(Number(x));
fLen = myarray.length ;
text = "<ul>";
for (i = 0; i < fLen; i++)
 {
  text += "<li>" + myarray[i] + "</li>";
}
text += "</ul>";

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}

function SortFunction()
{
myarray.sort(function(a, b){return a - b});
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myarray;
}

function AddFunction()
 {
var sum = 0 ;
var fLen ;
var i ;
fLen = myarray.length ;

for (i = 0; i < fLen; i++)
 {
 sum = sum + Number(myarray[i]);
  }
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = sum;
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: Can you confirm that my understanding is correct?

- Initially 3 arrays will be there and all are empty. You'll provide values to first array and save it. Then on click of a button, You'll provide a new number and using that number you'll multiply each item in the array and save the result in 2nd array. 
Once again divide each item in the 2nd array by that number and save it in 3rd array. Is that right?

Comment: @AshleyPlaza It is recommended that you mention the code in which you are having a problem to let users understand what solutions could be suggested.

Comment: Hi Ashley :) So first, you should provide code of what you have tried and where it is failing. If you have not yet tried and are feeling overwhelmed, fret not - it happens a lot as a newb. But in that case take a look at your question, and just start with the first thing and code that (don't worry about the rest), then do the next bit, then the next.... you actually _said_ exactly what you should be coding! :) if you have problems with any one of those steps just common back and provide your code. Best way to learn is to just DO...and don't overthink it. go ahead and break ish. then fix it :)

Comment: I just placed the code im working with i apologize for the confusion!